# Jenkins execute shell how to get the user who run the job

Tags: jenkins

I want sned a message to the executer,when the job tigger and complete. But the first question is how to get the user who run the job.

I look at the list of available environment variables. But I can't find the variables than I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this plugin can help you: [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)

Take a look to the usage example. This will tell you how the configuration works.